# Expand All Collapse All Button on a Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a Expand All, Collapse All button for my accordion. I would like the button at the top above the plus sign. On clicking Expand all it should expand all sections and vice versa for Collapse all.

I am not much of a coder but surely would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance. Looking forward for your help

Here is the code.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color:#eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  }


.active.accordion:hover 
{
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the accordion panel. Note: hidden by default */
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.panel ul, li {line-height: 0.5};
```

```html
<button class="accordion">'test1'</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> 
      <b>"Description :";<br/><br/> </b> "test 1.";<br/><br/>      
      <b>"DB :";<br/><br/> </b> "test,\u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 tes, \u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 test ";<br/><br/> 
      <b>"Query:";<br/><br/> </b> "test;";<br/><br/>   
      <b>"Additional Information:";<br/><br/> </b> "test.";<br/><br/>         
  </p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">'test1'</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p> 
      <b>"Description :";<br/><br/> </b> "test 1.";<br/><br/>      
      <b>"DB :";<br/><br/> </b> "test,\u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 tes, \u00A0 \u00A0 \u00A0 test ";<br/><br/> 
      <b>"Query:";<br/><br/> </b> "test;";<br/><br/>   
      <b>"Additional Information:";<br/><br/> </b> "test.";<br/><br/>         
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Code to expand all

```
document.querySelectorAll('.panel').forEach(node => node.style.display='block')
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion').forEach(node => node.classList.add('active'))
```

Code to collapse all

```
document.querySelectorAll('.panel').forEach(node => node.style.display='none')
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion').forEach(node => node.classList.remove('active'))
```

Comment: ...Sorry, not sure where to add this....and what about the buttons for this code....

Comment: copy paste the code to function names expandAll and collapseAll. create two buttons and call expandAll function on expand button click event and collapseAll function on collapse button click event